# Не выдает принт elif если if не сработал

Tags: python, python-3.x

возникла проблема, не могу понять в чем дело. Не выдает принт elif если if не сработал, кто может подсказать в чем проблема?

Код:

```
name = input('Введите Ваше имя: ')
age = int(input('Введите Ваш возраст: '))
weight = float(input('Введите Ваш Вес: '))


if weight >= 50 and weight <= 120 and age <= 30:
    print(name, str(age), 'года', float(weight), 'кг' )
    print('Состояние хорошее.')
elif age >= 30 and weight <= 50 and weight >= 120:
    print(name, str(age), 'года', float(weight), 'кг' )
    print('Вам требуется вести правильный образ жизни.')
elif age >40 and weight <= 50 and weight >= 120:
    print(name, str(age), 'года', float(weight), 'кг' )
    print('Вам требуется врачебный осмотр.')

#если не срабатывает условие if, не выдает принты elif
```

Comment: Все просто. Данные которые вы вводите не проходят поставленные вами условия. Добавьте просто else для случая который не попал ни в одно условие.

Comment: у вас очень странные условия, например: `weight <= 50 and weight >= 120`  или `elif age >= 30` и  `elif age >40`

Comment: Спасибо, изменил код, теперь все правильно работает: https://onlinegdb.com/r16F6vSAB

Comment: По Вашей логике если мне 46 лет и я вешу 300 кг. то мне "следует вести правильный образ жизни" вместо "требуется врачебный осмотр"

Comment: @DenisLanin если разобрались, добавьте ответом.

Comment: Большое спасибо всем за помощь, разобрался в нюансе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы произошла стопроцентная отработка какого-нибудь принта, нужно, чтобы последняя ветка была else:

```
if weight >= 50 and weight <= 120 and age <= 30:
    print(name, str(age), 'года', float(weight), 'кг' )
    print('Состояние хорошее.')
elif age >= 30 and weight <= 50 and weight >= 120:
    print(name, str(age), 'года', float(weight), 'кг' )
    print('Вам требуется вести правильный образ жизни.')
elif age >40 and weight <= 50 and weight >= 120:
    print(name, str(age), 'года', float(weight), 'кг' )
    print('Вам требуется врачебный осмотр.')
else:
    print(name, str(age), 'года', float(weight), 'кг' )
    print('Другой вариант.')
```